# Drupal 8: How to generate a taxonomy page based on tags

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

In Drupal 8, I have a blog posts assigned to different categories. Each category has its page: i.e. /blog/sports. Along the category, each post can be assigned to a tag or multiple tags: i.e. basketball, football, baseball. When content moderator adds a new post tag which didn't exist before, I need to generate a category page containing posts with that tag: i.e. /blog/basketball. Is this something that Drupal 8 does out of the box, or do I need to build a custom feature using the preprocessor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would comment but this account is low on rep, yes you can do that out of the box with Drupal 8. Here's some steps to help:

1. Got to Structure->Views
2. Select name for your view e.g. sport-blogs
3. Under displays, next to Mater click the add button and select "Page"
4. Under page settings to the right, enter the url path you want for your new page on. It doesn't need to be absolute.
5. Select Add under Filter criteria
   [image]

6. On the filter criteria select "taxonomy term" under Category
7. Select the name of your vocabulary of terms
8. Finally select all terms that you want shown or select only one e.g basketbal

Assuming all was set correct at this point you may be able to see a live preview based on your filters and existing content at the bottom of the view page. Once saved the view will be accessible to the path you've entered.